# Facebook RunWithFriend redirects to homepage

Tags: facebook

I'm following the [Canvas app Example](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/) of Facebook, but it seems that I'm unable to login succesfully, thus I'm unable to use the example app because I'm always redirected to the main page.

I think I set all the parameters correctly, except for the OAuth Migration that should be enabled. There is no such option in Facebook developer panel.

This is a screen of the main page as it appears to me after the login:
[image: Run with friends mainpage]

I have the same problem explained here:

[Canvas demo (runwithfriends) always redirects to main page under my own GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891670/canvas-demo-runwithfriends-always-redirects-to-main-page-under-my-own-gae)

with the exception that even the application on facebook GAE redirects me to the main page even if I successfully log in.

Did anyone experienced a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

eventually the facebook example is out of date. I committed a working example here 
https://github.com/fbsamples/web-runwithfriends